# Wordpress application gives 500

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm looking at a Wordpress WooCommerce CSV export plugin.  It works fine, except that if I ask it to export more than about 2000 records, something seems to be timing out and I get a 500 (not a 503, although the response body looks like it was made for 503s) after about 31 seconds.

My PHP installation is running on apache.  Some things from my apache conf:

```
Timeout 300

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ...
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-access.log
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-error.log
  LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

And select lines from my php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 300
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 4096
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
error_log = /var/log/httpd/php_errors.log
```

And the last line in my .htaccess:

```
php_value max_execution_time 300 # just in case
```

- The access log declared httpd.conf (using the CustomLog directive) logs the IP, request URL, response code, and user agent string for all requests, but nothing else.
- The error log declared in httpd.conf has nothing but lines that look like:

> [Thu May 07 15:33:24 2015] [debug] mod_headers.c(743): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()

- The error log declared in php.ini is an empty file, even after giving it chmod 666 or chowning it to apache:apache

I can't figure out why it appears to be timing out (judging from when it occurs), and why it gives a 500 instead of a 503 if it's a timeout, and why there is nothing in the error logs if it's really running into a 500.

Did I do something wrong?  What can I do to diagnose this?

Comment: For anyone interested in my particular problem, it turns out that wordpress queries are gigantic memory leakers, and should not be used for things like generating CSVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upping `memory_limit` in your php.ini, it's probably running out of room to store the export and then getting stuck and eventually timing out.

The entry on my Centos 7 server (php 5.4) looks like this:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 1024M
```

It's set to 1024M for Drupal.

Comment: Turns out it was a memory problem.  I tried changing memory allocation in php.ini before I posted the question and the 500 was occurring at the same time, so I figured it wasn't a memory problem.  It turns out that this setting was being overridden in the local .htaccess file.

Comment: Ahah!  Glad you fixed it =)